# При установки темы: Архив не удалось установить. В теме отсутствует таблица стилей style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, шаблоны, веб-программирование, zip

Скачал тему. Устанавливаю Мне выдаёт :

> Архив не удалось установить. В теме отсутствует таблица стилей style.css.

[Скрин](http://sd.uploads.ru/KybS8.png)

[Скачал здесь](http://www.nowdownload.ch/download.php?id=kxnfyfkwvr4jh)

Прочел, мол нужно изменить заголовок css. Поменял - все так же.

Как быть? Что нужно сделать...

Comment: @Ден Безфамильный, мы не будем качать неизвестные файлы непонятно откуда.

Comment: Вот та же тема здесь - http://narod.yandex.ru/disk/42601238001/rustruin.zip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то в этом архиве напихано все подряд. Попробуй распаковать архив и достань из него папки \rustik_v1.0.1\rustik_v1.0.1\rustik_v1.0.1\Rustik_WP_1.0.1_WESMASHEDIT\theme\rustik и \rustik_v1.0.1\rustik_v1.0.1\rustik_v1.0.1\Rustik_WP_1.0.1_WESMASHEDIT\plugins и закинь их соответственно в папки \wp-content\themes и \wp-content. Потом в админке вордпресса зайди в темы и попробуй активировать данную тему.

Comment: @kstv, спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ. Ты БОЖЕСТВЕНЕН!

Comment: с тебя адрес сайта

Comment: ну это же очевидно